# NUMA page_migration performance issue

Tags: java, linux, linux-kernel, numa, numactl

I'm running java application with ~80GB of memory-mapped files, which should be accessible via TCP, using AWS r3.8xlarge for that (I have it reserved, so migrating to non-NUMA architecture is not an option, at least right now) and have the following problem:

- during peak loads I noticed increased sys time and perf tool is showing that most of the time is spent in numa page_migration. Is it possible to replicate somehow memory across NUMA blocks to prevent continuous moving pages from one block to another? (all CPUs accessing all ~80G of memory)

(whole memory is read-only and may be pre-allocated during application startup.)

[image]

Comment: Why does you application need to access all the data randomly? Can you not have N services with 1/N of the data each running it its own numa region?

Comment: to keep application logic simple - it's like a big read-only database with random lookups. And each request may need data from different parts as well.

Comment: You are right that it would be better if the OS just knew to keep multiple copies, but what if you kept copies on disk.

Comment: I was thinking about running 2 java processes with privately mmaped files on each numa block - but it's little bit hard to support; so I'm wondering if it's an only possibility of getting replica in each numa block?

Comment: Are Transparent huge pages (THP) enabled? if so, try with THP disabled. I had seen heavy memory applications recommending to disable THP, for better performance.  `grep -i "^AnonHuge" /proc/meminfo` will show if they are in use

Comment: I've checked this, but they were turned off